# How to create custom camera with user specified buttons in Android

Tags: camera, android-camera

I have created FB app in that i need Camera option. of course i want 3 buttons, one to take a picture and 2nd to save and Main thing is 3rd button that is to directly upload images to facebook without saving to specified location im Mobile. I searched a lot but cant get like this.So please help me out. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Is there any options to customize the native camera.? I am also looking for customizing the default android device camera.